# Debug MapServer / PostGIS returning 0 results

Tags: postgis, wms, mapserver, google-earth

user30184 answered the same question here [Why is MapServer returning a blank image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149117/why-is-mapserver-returning-a-blank-image)

user30184 answers to start by specifying SRID and that it often has to do with extent and projection.

I imported some soils data with `ogr2ogr using -a_srs EPSG:4326`

I am attempting to view the WMS layer with Google Earth.  It currently shows a blank image.

My setup:

**Ubuntu** 14.0.4

**PostGIS**

> ```
> POSTGIS="2.1.2 r12389" 
> GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" 
> PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" 
> GDAL="GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10" LIBXML="2.9.1"
> LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER
> ```

**MapServer**

> MapServer version 6.4.2 OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML
> SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=GD SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE
> SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=RSVG SUPPORTS=ICONV
> SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT
> SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER
> SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS
> INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE

**Mapfile**

```
MAP
   DEBUG 5
   CONFIG "PROJ_DEBUG" "ON"
   NAME "WMS-test"
   CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/tmp/ms_error.txt"
   STATUS ON
   EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
   PROJECTION
     "init=epsg:4326"
   END
   IMAGECOLOR 55 55 55
   WEB
     METADATA
       "wms_title"          "WMS Test"
       "wms_onlineresource" "http://10.0.0.7/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/mapserver/wms.map&"
       "wms_srs"            "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
       "wms_enable_request" "*"
       "wms_formatlist"     "image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
       "wms_format"         "image/gif"
     END
   END # Web
   LAYER
     DEBUG 5
     NAME "polygons"
     PROJECTION
       "init=epsg:4326"
     END
     METADATA
       "wms_srs"            "EPSG:4326"
       "wms_name"           "polygon"
       "wms_title"          "polygon layer"
       "wms_server_version" "1.1.1"
       "wms_format"         "image/gif"
       "wms_include_items"  "all"
     END
     CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
     CONNECTION "user=xxxx password=xxxx dbname=xxxx host=localhost"
     PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
     DATA "geometry from polygon USING UNIQUE fid USING srid=4326"
     STATUS ON
     EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
     TYPE POLYGON
     CLASS
       STYLE
         COLOR 255 22 22
         OUTLINECOLOR 32 32 32
       END
     END
 END #layer
 END # Map File
```

**MapServer Logfile**

> CGI Request 1 on process 9224
>
> msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): enabling non-square pixels.
>
> msDrawMap(): kicking into non-square pixel preserving mode.
>
> msDrawMap(): rendering using outputformat named gif (GD/GIF).
>
> msDrawMap(): WMS/WFS set-up and query, 0.000s
>
> msPostGISLayerOpen called: geometry from polygon USING UNIQUE fid
> USING srid=4326
>
> msPostGISLayerOpen: No connection in pool, creating a fresh one.
>
> msConnPoolRegister(ssurgo,user=xxxx password=xxxx dbname=xxxx
> host=localhost,0xc7ad90)
>
> msPostGISLayerOpen: Got PostGIS version 20100.
>
> msPostGISLayerOpen: Forcing 2D geometries: yes.
>
> msPostGISLayerFreeItemInfo called.
>
> msPostGISLayerWhichShapes called.
>
> msPostGISParseData called.
>
> msPostGISParseData: unique_column=fid, srid=4326,
> geom_column_name=geometry, table_name=polygon
>
> msPostGISBuildSQL called.
>
> msPostGISBuildSQLItems called.
>
> msPostGISBuildSQLItems: 0 items requested.
>
> msPostGISBuildSQLFrom called.
>
> msPostGISBuildSQLWhere called.
>
> msPostGISBuildSQLSRID called.
>
> msPostGISBuildSQLSRID: SRID provided (4326)
>
> msPostGISBuildSQLBox called.
>
> msPostGISLayerWhichShapes query: select
> encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force2D("geometry"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"fid"
> from polygon where geometry &&
> ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-77.6373995911467
> 35.5916923817181,-77.6373995911467 35.6036240727873,-77.6170454186829 35.6036240727873,-77.6170454186829 35.5916923817181,-77.6373995911467 35.5916923817181))',4326)
>
> msPostGISLayerWhichShapes query status: PGRES_TUPLES_OK (2)
>
> msPostGISLayerWhichShapes got 0 records in result.
>
> msPostGISLayerNextShape called.
>
> msPostGISLayerFreeItemInfo called.
>
> msPostGISLayerClose called: geometry from polygon USING UNIQUE fid
> USING srid=4326
>
> msConnPoolRelease(ssurgo,user=xxxx password=xxxx dbname=xxxx
> host=localhost,0xc7ad90)
>
> msDrawMap(): Layer 0 (ssurgo), 0.015s
>
> msDrawMap(): Drawing Label Cache, 0.000s
>
> msDrawMap() total time: 0.015s
>
> msSaveImage(stdout) total time: 0.002s
>
> mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): 0.017s
>
> msFreeMap(): freeing map at 0xc0b630.
>
> freeLayer(): freeing layer at 0xc14160.
>
> msPostGISLayerIsOpen called.
>
> msConnPoolClose(user=xxxx password=xxxx dbname=xxxx
> host=localhost,0xc7ad90)

Answer (score 1):

> msPostGISLayerWhichShapes got 0 records in result.

tells me that there comes nothing back from the database. Are you sure that your soil data is in WGS84? You could verify with QGIS for example that there is data in your database. Or you could do a simple query inside PostGIS to see if something is there, something like this to check your data's extent and see the coordinates (adopt the query to your situation please):

```
SELECT ST_Extent(the_geom) as bextent FROM sometable;
```

I am just asking because the ogr2ogr -a_srs option assigns an SRS to the data, even if the assigned SRS is different to the data's actual SRS.

Comment: thanks @Frank!  here's the output  \BOX(1054154.3037 1345250.5414,1838923.5134 1688864.6571)\  The data comes in Albers 4326.  I'm slowly learning GIS, but clearly see the coords aren't in WGS84.  Is it recommended to put them into WGS84 upon import?  I thought I could dynamically re-project.  I only intend of using WGS84 for the current work I'm doing.  I'm guessing that might boost performance, too.

Comment: I re-imported with the following `-s_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "EPSG:4326"` and a bbox ST_Extent result now looks like `BOX(-80.1021918303873 49.6667785692599,-67.9711156466496 52.4666193122625)` .. no results yet, but working through some config file changes

Comment: ok, so now I can connect with QGIS and zoom-to-layer and see that it is correctly determining coordinates based on an OSM base-map ( the data is over North Carolina in USA ) .. no results from postgis yet, but seems like I'm getting closer

Comment: now, if I re-add the WMS endpoint to QGIS, then right-click and "add layer", it looks like it is pulling all of the polygons.  the query looks like this `msPostGISLayerWhichShapes query: select encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force2D(“my_geome
try"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"fid" from polygon where my_geometry && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-179.79020979
021 -89.7902097902098,-179.79020979021 89.7902097902098,179.79020979021 89.7902097902098,179.79020979021 -89.79020
97902098,-179.79020979021 -89.7902097902098))',4326)` ... I had to increase the timeout because it is pulling aLOT of records (1056549 records)

Comment: I would debug one software layer after the other. If your data is now in PostGIS and in the right coordinate system, I would use the [shp2img](http://mapserver.org/utilities/shp2img.html) program that comes with mapserver to test your mapfile. If your query takes too long you could limit the returned records to speed testing up. Or you could add an index (See [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/optimization/vector.html#postgis)/[PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#idp45366608) docs). If shp2img works, you go ahead and test the OGC capabilities with QGIS.

Comment: thanks again @Frank. I'm scripting the drop/recreation of my db to make things easier and will test with shp2img